# Firebug shows data stream but not calendar?

Tags: mysql, json, fullcalendar

after many days [9] I have come to a point where I need to either look for another calendar or just give up.. Using fullcalendar I have json-events.php sending mysql data through to my staff_calendar.php page, the datastream shows in firebug, the calendar shows in the page but the data doesnt appear in the actual fullcalendar, can anyone please help?

What could be stopping this data rendering in my page?

xxjson-events.php

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal);
$query_rsXXCal = "Select events.* , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date) as start_date, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_date) as end_date From events";
$rsXXCal = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsXXCal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsXXCal);
$totalRows_rsXXCal = mysql_num_rows($rsXXCal);

        $result = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
             $eventsArray = array();
             $eventsArray['title'] = $row['title'];
             $eventsArray['start'] = $row['start_date'];
             $eventsArray['end'] = $row['end_date']; 
        }  

        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo json_encode($eventsArray)
?>
```

This outputs both in browser & firebug as:

```
{"title":"Visit","start":"1330077690","end":"1330081890"}
```

calendar.php

```
script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/xxjson-events.php',
            async: 'false' // No longer asynchronous
        }
    ],
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        }
    }); });

</script>
```

Thanks to anyone who can shed any light on this, however small it may be!

Answer (score 0):

Well first I suspect it is because

```
async: 'false'
```

Should be...

```
async: false
```

and also, by default allDayDefault is set to true so if you are not displaying allDay events then you won't actually see them.

If you don't want to show allDay events then add...

```
allDayDefault: false
```

...to the initialization. On the other hand if you do want to show allDay events then you need to add another field to your database table called allDay and set it to true or false depending on what the event calls for. Pull it out through the array and it should display. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your input really appreciate the help. I tried the above but no joy, I only put in the async & alldaydefault options as a test as nothing else works. This is very strange it just wont render in the calendar, if it helps I have uploaded the 2 php files & mysql tble here, wonder if or you anyone has time you could try in your environment to confirm its not the code thats wrong? http://ghldatastream.co.uk.predns.ourwindowsnetwork.com/fullcal_json.zip

Many thanks again

Comment: Quick update dont think it will help but when I use firebug to view the json in demo file & my file I note the demo output is wrapped in [{ }], mine is just {}, could this be causing the problem?

demo - [{"title":"visit","start":"1330077690","end":"1330081890"}]
my page - {"title":"Visit","start":"1330077690","end":"1330081890"}

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE GOT IT! So, there were no errors from fullcalendar parser. I though JSON is a one standard... Unfortunately it isn't (mayby only in my situation :P ).
So, JSON response from servlet looks like below:

```
{"id":"68","title":"ddd","start":"2012-03-28","end":"2012-03-29"}
```

I just add "[" and "]" before sent from servlet and it works!

```
[{"id":"68","title":"ddd","start":"2012-03-28","end":"2012-03-29"}]
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone like me ;-)

Comment: Hi Simon, glad you got it working & posting the result, I wonder if you would be kind enough to send me the 2 files now you have it working? I too have the correct format of [{}] now but my data still doesnt pull through, really bugging me now!